# 私は４つの県に住んだことがあります。

Tags: grammar, particle-の

In the following transcription, it seems to me that the first の follows the pattern AのB, where A is an attribute of B (e.g. カラーの写真). However, I am at a loss as to the meaning of the second の.

> 日本は４７の都道府県があります。私は４つの県に住んだことがあります。

Comment: Please link a source

Comment: This is one way to construct a counter pattern, hopefully this answers your question.